# convert data types when extracting information from a database using sql in R language

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, database, type-conversion

I am trying to extract some information from three tables connected with inner join. However, when I try to do the on statement, the program tells me that one of the columns are type varchar and the other is type text. I can't use "=" operators on them. I don't know which column is text and which one is varchar because when I try to view them in R studio, they all show up as type character. I tried convert, cast, and use LIKE instead of =, but none of it worked.

I can't change the type of variable of the column because they are not my tables. These are SQL codes that is going to be part of a query and submit to the database through R languages which will receive and process any returned data.

I first tried

```
"ON CONVERT(varchar(10), A.A11) = CONVERT(varchar(10), B.B2)"
```

then

```
"ON CAST(A.A11 AS text) = CAST(B.B2 AS text)"
```

and also

```
"ON A.A11 LIKE B.B2"
```

I tried changing them to text and varchar, but it is still not working.
The error message is

```
42000 402 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The data types varchar and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.
```

I followed the tutorials and answers online so it should not have any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me in sql server. attached is sample code for you

```
create table #Test_1 (
val_1 varchar(10) null
,check_case text null
)


create table #Test_2 (
val_2 varchar(10) null
,check_case varchar(10) null
)

insert into #Test_1  values
('A','test_test')
,('B','check123')
,('C','holaman')


insert into #Test_2  values
('A','check123')
,('B','test_test')
,('C','holaman')



select t1.*, t2.*
from #Test_1 t1
inner join #Test_2 t2 on t1.val_1 = t2.val_2 and convert(varchar,t1.check_case) = convert(varchar , t2.check_case )
```

Comment: you issue will reside when you pass it as a big query to R-code. Which may or may not be able to handle all sql server data-types. And if that is the case you may have to find common ground AND work to perhaps change the table structures.